# Finding shortest calculation of the sum of a subset of a group, given sums for other previously summed subsets

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, integer-lattices

Say $S=\{g\in G\}$ is a set of elements in an abelian group $G$ whose group operation $(+)$ is expensive to compute. Given a subset $T\subset S$, we want to compute the sum of $T$'s elements, $\sigma_T=\sum_{g\in T}g$. Say we have a collection of other subsets of $S$, $U=\{T_i\}$, for which the sums $\sigma_{T_i}=\sum_{g\in T_i}g$ are already known. We can assume $U$ contains the singleton subsets of $S$, since $\sigma_{\{g\}}=g$. Hence   $\sigma_T$ can always be expressed as a linear combination of the $\sigma_{T_i}$'s, namely $\sum_{g\in T}\sigma_{\{g\}}=\sum_{g\in T}g=\sigma_T$. I'd like to find the linear combination$\sum_i a_i\sigma_{T_i}=\sigma_T$, which minimizes $\sum_i|a_i|$, i.e., which computes the sum with the least number of group operations.

It seems likely that the problem of actually finding this optimum is NP-complete, so I'm looking for good heuristics, ideally with some reasonable bound on the distance from optimality. Also, any references to papers discussing this problem would be great. Finally, storing the $\sigma_{T_i}$'s is somewhat expensive for me, too, so I'm also interested in heuristics for deciding which $\sigma_{T_i}$'s should be stored, given a sequence $\{T_1, T_2, \ldots\}$, and fixed costs for storage, retrieval and group operations.

Comment: To be clear, is there any reason to have $a_i>1$?  Or can we assume $a_i\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: I'm interested in optimizing over $a_i\in\mathbb Z$, since the $T_i$'s need not be disjoint. So, for instance, the best sum could be of the form $\sigma_{T_1}+\sigma_{T_2}-\sigma_{T_1\cap T_2}$.

Comment: OK, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_i\in\{0,1\}$, this is the *[exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem*, which is NP-complete.  There are specialized algorithms for it, or you can use integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary variable $a_i$ indicate whether subset $T_i \in U$ is used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i a_i$ subject to linear constraints:
$$
\sum_{i: g\in T_i} a_i = \begin{cases}1&\text{if $g\in T$}\\0&\text{if $g\in S \setminus T$}\end{cases}
$$

More generally, let $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ be the (signed) number of times that $T_i$ is used.  Let $b_i$ represent $|a_i|$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i b_i$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i: g\in T_i} a_i &= \begin{cases}1&\text{if $g\in T$}\\0&\text{if $g\in S \setminus T$}\end{cases}\\
b_i &\ge a_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
b_i &\ge -a_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm interested in optimizing over $a_i\in\mathbb Z$, since the $T_i$'s need not be disjoint. So, for instance, the best sum could be of the form $\sigma_{T_1}+\sigma_{T_2}-\sigma_{T_1\cap T_2}$.

Comment: My second formulation allows that.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.

Comment: I made some corrections just now.